# Google Maps API using Retrofit GET call

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit, google-places-api

I want to pass in the latitude and longitude values to the `location` attribute of the Google Maps Autocomplete API call but I have no idea how to form the GET call in Retrofit. The URL should ultimately look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&types=address&input=user_input&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=50000&key=API_KEY
```

What I currently have in my Retrofit interface:

```
public interface GooglePlacesAutoCompleteAPI
{
    String BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/";
    String API_KEY = "mykey";  //not the actual key obviously

    //This one works fine
    @GET("json?&types=(cities)&key=" + API_KEY)
    Call<PlacesResults> getCityResults(@Query("input") String userInput);

    //This is the call that does not work
    @GET("json?&types=address&key=" + API_KEY)
    Call<PlacesResults> getStreetAddrResults(@Query("input") String userInput, 
                                             @Query("location") double latitude, double longitude,
                                             @Query("radius") String radius);
}
```

My error is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3) for method GooglePlacesAutoCompleteAPI.getStreetAddrResults`

So how can I correctly setup the GET method for `getStreetAddrResults()`?

Also, are my data types correct for latitude/longitude and radius? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interface should look like this:

```
public interface API {
    String BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

    @GET("/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
    Call<PlacesResults> getCityResults(@Query("types") String types, @Query("input") String input, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") Integer radius, @Query("key") String key);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

API service = retrofit.create(API.class);


service.getCityResults(types, input, location, radius, key).enqueue(new Callback<PlacesResults>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PlacesResults> call, Response<PlacesResults> response) {
        PlacesResults places = response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<PlacesResults> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Of course you should give a value to the parameters.

Comment: Right as you had answered, I had just figured it out. The key was to make a string out of the latitude and longitude values. Trying to pass them as two separate parameters caused the problems. Thanks for the in depth answer, I got it to work :]